# AngularJS Template URL Loads Before Authorization Resolves

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to determine if there is a way to prevent the load of a $routeProvider templateUrl before the promises of functions defined in resolve are resolved. (Note: pages are not displaying, but they are loading).

Here's an example of a route definition:

```
$routeProvider.when(path: "/myRoute",
    templateUrl: "myUrl.tmpl.html",
    resolve: {
        authorize: function(AuthorizationService) {
            return AuthorizationService.authorizeRoute();
        }
    }
);
```

If I look in the dev tools, the application LOADS the templateURL, but doesn't display it. I would prefer that a user not be able to view the template in Developer tools, but the template load seems to be decoupled from the function call in resolve.

I would like to do one of two things:

1. Prevent the load of the template until the authorization function resolves.
2. Define a fake URL ('blank.html') in templateUrl, then dynamically load the "real" url if authorization is successful.

Can anyone help?

Edit: This is NOT a duplicate of my previous question. I am trying prevent the background load (not display) of the templateUrl before resolution, which seems to happen regardless of the results of authorization call. If this is not possible, I want to load a fake page on authorization fail.

Comment: You need  probably to return the promise in the resolve method

Comment: The promise in resolve works fine. However, the templateUrl is loaded regardless of the result of the resolve function.

Comment: That was a typo, which I've now fixed. The promise returns fine, but templateUrl still loads.

Comment: probably it related to the fact that there is nothing to construct, (u r using only template), try to construct a component with a controller

Comment: What version of angular do u use?

Comment: AngularJS 1.5. Cannot update to newer Angular at this time.

Comment: just add an empty controller :]